# PS3 and 5.1 sound

Tags: ps3, audio-hardware

I have this PS3 that I would like to use for playing but also see some bluray movies... but I also have a nice Tv.

I'm wondering if someone could provide me some info about what kind of hardware should I have in order to have those some 5.1 columns for TV + PS3 so that, whateaver a 5.1 is available I could have it.

Can I have your help for this, sort of, general question?

Comment: I'm sorry, but as is mentioned in the FAQ, shopping recommendation questions are off-topic here.

Comment: generic answer, get a decent to good receiver that has HDMI pass-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 new pieces of hardware:

- (rather obvious) A speakerset with 5 boxes and a subwoofer that you can connect to a receiver
- A so-called 5.1 receiver. You can get this starting at about $200, but more expensive usually means more features and better quality

You then have 2 different options to connect:

1. HDMI Cable: if your receiver has HDMI passthrough you can connect a HDMI cable from your PS3 to it and then a HDMI cable from your receiver to your TV. This also enables 7.1 but won't work with PS2 titles.
2. A optical cable: a more common way. Make sure to select only the audio-output formats your receiver supports

How to configure your PS3 can be found [on the playstation manuals site](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/audiooutput.html)

Answer (score 0):

My PS3 feeds my TV via HDMI, and the TV has a fiber-optic output that runs to my 5.1 amplifier.